# Order by ID and Price woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, custom-wordpress-pages

I’m using a custom loop to display woocommerce products on a page, I need order it by range price and products ids like below :

```html
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'orderby'   => 'ID', 
        'order'     => 'desc', 
        'meta_query' => array( 'relation ' => 'AND',
            array(
               'key' => '_price',
               'value' => array( $minPrice, $maxPrice ),
               'type' => 'numeric',
               'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
               'order' => 'asc')
         )
       );
```

Could someone help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this snippet.

```
$args = array(
        'post_status'   => 'publish',
        'post_type'     => 'product',
        'orderby'       => 'ID', 
        'order'         => 'asc', 
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key'      => '_price',
                'value' => array( $minPrice, $maxPrice ),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            )
        )
    );
```

You can get more ideas from this kind of topics [WooCommerce search products between price range using WP_Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28367830/woocommerce-search-products-between-price-range-using-wp-query)